# How do you INNER JOIN a table on a certain condition in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I have a series of joins in my SELECT statement that I wish to execute. **However, I would like to execute the final join (the INNER JOIN) only if a certain condition is met.** 
The query creates a CTE by separating a comma separated string of words into a table of words. I have another table that I am joining this CTE to in order to filter the results. However, if the user does not put in any string, I do not not want to join this table. Is there any way to put some condition on an INNER JOIN?

```
SELECT  dt.Document_ID, 
    dt.Document_NAME, 
    c.Company_ID,
    c.Company_NAME, 
    ct.Category_ID,
    ct.Category_NAME,
    dt.Employee_ID,
    e.First_NAME AS Employee_First_NAME,
    e.Last_NAME AS Employee_Last_NAME,
    p.Project_ID,
    p.Project_NAME,
    dt.Document_DATE,
    dt.Updated_By_ID,
    u.First_NAME AS Updated_First_NAME,
    u.Last_NAME AS Updated_Last_NAME
FROM Documents_T1 AS dt
    LEFT JOIN Companies_T1 AS c ON c.Company_ID=dt.Company_ID
    LEFT JOIN Categories_T1 AS ct ON ct.Category_ID=dt.Category_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users_T1 AS e ON e.User_ID=dt.Employee_ID
    LEFT JOIN Projects_T1 AS p ON p.Project_ID=dt.Project_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users_T1 AS u ON u.User_ID=dt.Updated_By_ID 
    INNER JOIN TagsCTE AS tcte ON tcte.Document_ID=dt.Document_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't want a join at all.  You want to put this information in a where clause.

```
SELECT
    dt.Document_ID, 
    dt.Document_NAME, 
    c.Company_ID,
    c.Company_NAME, 
    ct.Category_ID,
    ct.Category_NAME,
    dt.Employee_ID,
    e.First_NAME AS Employee_First_NAME,
    e.Last_NAME AS Employee_Last_NAME,
    p.Project_ID,
    p.Project_NAME,
    dt.Document_DATE,
    dt.Updated_By_ID,
    u.First_NAME AS Updated_First_NAME,
    u.Last_NAME AS Updated_Last_NAME 
FROM Documents_T1 AS dt
    LEFT JOIN Companies_T1 AS c ON c.Company_ID=dt.Company_ID
    LEFT JOIN Categories_T1 AS ct ON ct.Category_ID=dt.Category_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users_T1 AS e ON e.User_ID=dt.Employee_ID
    LEFT JOIN Projects_T1 AS p ON p.Project_ID=dt.Project_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users_T1 AS u ON u.User_ID=dt.Updated_By_ID  
WHERE
    dt.ID IN (SELECT Document_ID FROM TagsCTE)
    OR
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TagsCTE) IS NULL
```

In simpler terms with a table D and table T

```
SELECT * FROM D
WHERE
 D.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T)
 OR (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM T) IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't like the syntax `(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM T) IS NULL` because it's misleading. It does succeed if T has no rows, but it would also succeed if the first ID it selects happens to have a null value (maybe not possible in this scenario, but who knows...). If you go this structure, I'd suggest `(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T) = 0` or `NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM T)` or something that's more clear.

Comment: @JoeEnos , after reading the question I don't believe there will be NULL values in the TagsCTE table.  It may not be pretty but since you can't conditionally include a table in the where clause this is the most efficient way around it.  You could also create a stored procedure that calls one of 2 SQL statements depending on if there is data in TagsCTE.  Again, it wouldn't be graceful to look at but it would be functional.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `INNER JOIN` is going to be performed regardless if it is in the code.  You could, however, use a `LEFT JOIN` and include *in the join condition* whatever test you would use to determine if you should perform the join or not.

The effect of this would be that if the condition was true, you would perform the join based on the rest of the criteria, and if it were false, you would get NULL results back for the joined table in those rows.

```
SELECT  dt.Document_ID, 
    dt.Document_NAME, 
    c.Company_ID,
    c.Company_NAME, 
    ct.Category_ID,
    ct.Category_NAME,
    dt.Employee_ID,
    e.First_NAME AS Employee_First_NAME,
    e.Last_NAME AS Employee_Last_NAME,
    p.Project_ID,
    p.Project_NAME,
    dt.Document_DATE,
    dt.Updated_By_ID,
    u.First_NAME AS Updated_First_NAME,
    u.Last_NAME AS Updated_Last_NAME
FROM Documents_T1 AS dt
    LEFT JOIN Companies_T1 AS c ON c.Company_ID=dt.Company_ID
    LEFT JOIN Categories_T1 AS ct ON ct.Category_ID=dt.Category_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users_T1 AS e ON e.User_ID=dt.Employee_ID
    LEFT JOIN Projects_T1 AS p ON p.Project_ID=dt.Project_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users_T1 AS u ON u.User_ID=dt.Updated_By_ID 
    **LEFT** JOIN TagsCTE AS tcte ON tcte.Document_ID=dt.Document_ID AND <<condition>>
```